# Maven: Generate both jar and war for the project using same pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project and i need to generate both jar and war of the project using same pom.xml.
So when i run 'mvn clean install' it should generate both jar and war in my ~/m2 directory.
I needed this jar to build my second project.
Below is the sample pom.xml.

```
<artifactId>demo-service</artifactId>
<name>demo-service</name>
<description>service demo</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
.
.
.
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-archive</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Split your project into a jar that you reuse for both your war and your other project. Don't try to shoehorn the build into some frankenstein build that does both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try options `archiveClasses` and `attachClasses` of [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)

So your configuration can look like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans i already tried this and it generate the jar but it append -classes in the e nd. Can we have it without -classes in the end.

Comment: It is not a problem you can add `<classifier>classes</classifier>` to your dependency

Answer (score -1):

You should also use `maven-install-plugin`

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>demo-service</artifactId>
    <name>demo-service</name>
    <description>service demo</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    ....

    <build>
        <finalName>web-app-global-exceptions</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>inplace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-a-jar</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                          <phase>package</phase>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>single</goal>
                          </goals>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                       <archive>
                           <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                 <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                           </manifest>
                       </archive>
                       <descriptorRefs>
                           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                      </descriptorRefs>
                 </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Add-2-local-repository</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <!-- <file>${project.build.directory}\${project.artifactId}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</file> -->
                            <!-- <file>${project.build.directory}\${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</file> -->
                            <file>${project.build.directory}\${project.artifactId}.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```